# Converting a numpy narray (row form) to image

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, matplotlib, scipy

I have a numpy ndarry of the order of 28x11105. Each row is the 105x105 image RGB values. So basically each row is an image and thus I have 28 such images(28 rows).

I wanted to check if I can convert first image(then others) by doing something like this:

```
plt.imshow(X[0,:], interpolation='nearest').
```

Where X is the bumpy ndarry as above.

It said , the dimension is wrong for image. How do I convert each row depicting all pixel values of an image to the equivalent image.

EDIT:

My original image is this lets say: 
[image]

What I am getting after using the above imshow on the pixel value of this image is this:

[image]

Again my data matrix is as mentioned above. 28x11025. Each row being the 105x105 pixel values of the image.

EDIT2:

I used np.rot, and then plotted again. Also did grey_r. So while _r thing now flips the colour and gives the right colour, rot thing creates a problem as below . My Xt is 28x11025 matrix. So 28 images with their pixel values. I am currently checking the plotting code for first row or first image. Will eventually plot all 28 images , so would the remove the indexing on Xt2.

```
Xt2=np.rot90(Xt)
plt.imshow(Xt2[0,:].reshape(105,105), interpolation='nearest',cmap=cm.Greys_r)

>>>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-186-12e4a649eaf2> in <module>()
     48 #plt.imshow(Xt[0,:].reshape(105,105), interpolation='nearest',cmap=cm.Greys)
     49 Xt2=np.rot90(Xt)
---> 50 plt.imshow(Xt2[0,:].reshape(105,105), interpolation='nearest',cmap=cm.Greys_r)
     51 
     52 

ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
```

EDIT3:

So Instead of rot I used Transpose. Something like this:

plt.imshow(Xt[0,:].reshape(105,105).T, interpolation='nearest',cmap=cm.Greys_r) and it gives me the correct flipped output. (Don't go with the blurriness at smile. THis is the noise added images).

[image]

Now to print all the 28 images of this matrix, I am running a for loop.

```
for x in range(20):
    plt.imshow(Xt[x,:].reshape(105,105).T,interpolation='nearest',cmap=cm.Greys_r)
```

But the problem is , I want all 28 images as side by side images in notebook. Go all the way to the width of notebook and then continue on another line. But this basically plots the image on top of the previous one hence it just shows me the last image. How do I rectify this?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the way to unflatten your image arrays would be:

```
ims = X.reshape(28, 105, 105)
```

if each row is 11025 values long with one value for each pixel or:

```
ims = X.reshape(28, 105, 105, 3)
```

if each row contains a sequence of RGB values for each of the 11025 pixels. However, you state that each row is 11105 values long, which doesn't match with either of these... how exactly is your data packed into the array X?

EDIT: Note that if you see colours, you're probably looking at Matplotlib's default colormap for the image. To show a grayscale image, use:

```
import matplotlib.cm as cm
plt.imshow(ims[0], cmap=cm.Greys)
```

etc.
You can use an inverted colormap (as you seem to need) by appending `_r`: `cm.Greys_r` in the above argument, `cmap`. If your image seems upside down or needs rotating, consider one or both of

```
im2 = np.rot90(im)
im2 = np.flipud(im)
```

Comment: I am sorry. I meant 11025(105*105). So what I have is, a bumpy ndarray, which has 28 rows of 11025 dimension. Each row is basically an image. So each image is converted into RGB values which is on one row. So there would be 28 such images corresponding to each row of this array. I was trying for first row(first image) to check if I could get the corresponding image. I have to eventually do for all 28 rows to get corresponding 28 images.

Comment: If you only have 11025 numbers for each `105 x 105` image then you must have a greyscale image (for you would need `105 x 105 x 3 = 33075` numbers to have RGB components for each pixel. Does `plt.imshow(X[0,:].reshape(105,105), interpolation='nearest')` show the expected image?

Comment: It works but it has some colours coming up. Like green background etc. I need in Grayscale. It does produce the image though. But with some background colors. Any idea how to remove those?

Comment: See my edit: you might just be seeing Matplotlib's default colormap for the image colors, which you can set to grayscale as suggested.

Comment: Hi xnx, Need a quick help. I used your command but it is not giving me back the same image for which I have the pixels and plotted. How to get the same image back when plotting using its pixels? Pls see Edit for more.

Comment: I've made another edit. Note that `imshow` isn't really an image viewer in the sense that it shows you the picture your browser would for a .jpg file-- it has its own colormap and interpolation routines.

Comment: Don't rotate your whole array of images, just rotate one image at a time: `Xt2=np.rot90(Xt[0,:])`

Comment: Doesn't work. Says this: 

    175     m = asanyarray(m)
    176     if m.ndim < 2:
--> 177         raise ValueError("Input must >= 2-d.")
    178     k = k % 4
    179     if k == 0:

ValueError: Input must >= 2-d.

I did same thing. 
Xt2=np.rot90(Xt[0,:])

Comment: Hi xnxx. Please check the edit. I have used Transpose instead of Rot and it works if done at an individual level and not on the whole matrix. Check the edit for more details.

Comment: I'm glad it works for you. You should now accept if this answer has solved your first problem and ask a new question if you want more help.

Comment: Do you know how to plot all the images side by side instead of getting it one over the other in iPython notebook as asked in Edit# above?